# How to setup 6in4 tunnel?

Tags: ipv6

Say my Android device is on an IPv4-only network and I have a [6in4 tunnel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6in4) (e.g. from HE/tunnelbroker.net) - how can I configure my device such that IPv6 traffic goes through that tunnel?

Background: on a stock Linux system you can connect to the 6in4 tunnel via issuing 5 iproute2 commands or so.

Answer (score 0):

For that, I suggest you look at this application,[isatapd](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.saschahlusiak.isatapd&hl=en) (requires root).
It seems to match your description;

> ISATAP is a IPv6 in IPv4 tunnel mechanism that allows clients to get a
>   global routeable IPv6 address over an IPv4 only network. The isatapd
>   tool for Linux helps with the automatic configuration of the tunnel
>   and the client endpoint and is shipped in this app and run as root.

Alternatively the same developer has a similar app [IPv6Config](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=to.doc.android.ipv6config&hl=en&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Dipv6config%20google%20play&pcampaignid=APPU_1_Vm76WMPKAoecvQTZmoD4AQ) (root required). From description;

> IPv6Config allows to configure some of the IPv6 kernel settings.
>   Currently, it allows to automatically enable the "Privacy Extensions
>   for Stateless Address Autoconfiguration in IPv6" as specified in IETF
>   RFC4941 and implemented by the standard Linux kernel and to establish
>   6to4 tunnels for IPv6 connectivity with providers that only provide
>   IPv4 addresses so far.

Hope this helps

Comment: I was hoping for something that doesn't require root. I mean - since there are similar apps for other tunnel types that don't require root - e.g. the OpenVpn app and IPv6Droid (doesn't support 6in4).

Comment: I think for that setup you  pneed to pass ipv6 traffic through ssh tunnel e.g a combo of open vpn and ssh tunnel